# How to modify the appearance of the name in the footnote (style is verbose-trad2)?

Tags: biblatex

I am using verbose-trad2, and I can't find how to modify the look of the name in the footnote. 
Now it looks like that : 
[image]

9 and 10 are perfect, but 11 is not, it shoud be like number 9, but with the forname, so :
[image]

Here is my current code :

```
\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay=false]{csquotes} % gère les différents styles de citations selon la langue
\makeatletter
  \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart 4095 = {\nobreakspace\xpg@nospace}% "«  " -> "«~"
  \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}
\makeatother

\usepackage[sorting=nyt,bibstyle=enc,citestyle=verbose-trad2,ibidpage=true,idemtracker=false,backend=biber]{biblatex} % https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles
\addbibresource{../bibliographie.bib}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\enquote{#1}} % résout un problème avec les articles d'encyclopédie
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{doi}} % enlève le doi dans les notes de bas de page
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{% Permet la traduction de termes
    in               = {in},
    idem             = {Id.},
    idemsm           = {Id.},
    idemsf           = {Ead.},
    idemsn           = {Id.},
    idempm           = {Eid.},
    idempf           = {Eaed.},
    idempn           = {Ead.},
    idempp           = {Eid.},
    ibidem           = {\textit{Ibid\adddot}},
    andothers        = {\textit{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
    january          = {janv\adddot},
    february         = {f\'evr\adddot},
    march            = {mars},
    byeditor         = {(dir\adddot)},
    bycriticaleditor = {éd\adddot},
    volume           = {t.},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}\isdot} % Ajout d'une virgule après le titre d'un ouvrage dans @incollection, donc avant le in

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % D'abord le nom de famille dans les notes de bas de page
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

I have tried really hard to understand the bbx and cbx files, but it is a nightmare, and I can't find no tutorial or documentation.

Thank you in advance !

PS : I have continued the investigation by copying the code from the biblatex github, and it seems that the method \printnames{author} is the one doing the job. See below :

```
\newbibmacro*{authorstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{authortype}
    {}
    {
            \printtext[authortype]{%
       \ifbibxstring{\thefield{authortype}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{author}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{author}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{authortype}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{authortype}}}}
                 {\thefield{authortype}}}
        }
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {
            \printnames{author}% C'est ici qu'il faut modifier
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
```

Comment: For future questions please consider adding a complete example document that we can compile directly without any additions. This would be called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (or MWEB: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and would start with `\documentclass`, it would contain the relevant bits of the preamble (pretty much what is already shown in the question), but then it would also have `\begin{document}...\end{document}` with a bit of dummy content to reproduce something like the screenshot you show. ...

Comment: ... With bibliographies it is also helpful to include one or two example `.bib` entries from `bibliographie.bib` (or use `biblatex-examples.bib` which is available on all systems with `biblatex`). An MWE makes sure we are all seeing the same thing and helps those trying to answer your question get started because it does not require them to come up with things you already have in your document on their own.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, sure will do next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not only using `verbose-trad2`. You are using the citation style `verbose-trad2`, but for the bibliography you are using `biblatex-enc`'s `enc`. Bibliography and citation styles are not completely independent and especially in a `verbose` citation style the bibliography style plays a role.

In this case `enc.bbx` modifies the name format for the bibliography, which also affects citations by redefining [the bibmacro `name:family-given` to include parentheses around given names and other name parts](https://github.com/Jean-Baptiste-Camps/biblatex-enc/blob/dc9f13f95c4409588c45b422b9e353371e766e9a/enc.bbx#L246-L273).

We can undo that change by copying the original definition from `biblatex.def`.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay=false]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  sorting=nyt, bibstyle=enc, citestyle=verbose-trad2,
  ibidpage=true, idemtracker=false]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}\isdot}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
    in               = {in},
    idem             = {Id\adddot},
    idemsm           = {Id\adddot},
    idemsf           = {Ead\adddot},
    idemsn           = {Id\adddot},
    idempm           = {Eid\adddot},
    idempf           = {Eaed\adddot},
    idempn           = {Ead\adddot},
    idempp           = {Eid\adddot},
    ibidem           = {\textit{Ibid\adddot}},
    andothers        = {\textit{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
    january          = {janv\adddot},
    february         = {f\'evr\adddot},
    march            = {mars},
    byeditor         = {(dir\adddot)},
    bycriticaleditor = {éd\adddot},
    volume           = {t\adddot},
}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{worman}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{worman}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson Emma et Ryde Ulf//Worman Nancy]

This will also change the output in the bibliography accordingly, which is probably a good thing for consistency.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tex wizard ! It works like a charm.